# AngularDart: ng-repeat filter update

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to apply a filter to a `ng-repeat`. But it's not updating when my model changes.

```dart
<th ng-repeat='column in cmp.columns | filter {visible:"true"}'>
  {{column.title}}
</th>
```

I'm getting the columns via a future in my component if thats makes any difference.

```dart
cols.getColumns().then ((columns){
  this.columns = columns;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Current workaround

moving the filter logic into my component:

```dart
List get visibleColumnNames => columns.where((col) => col['visible'] == true)
  .map((col) => col['name']).toList();
```

Still would like to know how to do this in the template with a filter.